# turtlebot_teleop: control moving around keys

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am going through the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials/indigo/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world) for the turtlebot simulation on Gazebo. I can make the robot move with the command.
I see the on-screen instructions:

```
Control Your Turtlebot!
---------------------------
Moving around:
   u    i    o
   j    k    l
   m    ,    .

q/z : increase/decrease max speeds by 10%
w/x : increase/decrease only linear speed by 10%
e/c : increase/decrease only angular speed by 10%
space key, k : force stop
anything else : stop smoothly

CTRL-C to quit
```

I have movements:

- ***u/o, m/.*** turn around a point,
- ***j/l*** turn in place,
- ***i/,*** move forward, backward.

What is the difference between ***u/o***  and ***m/.***? How can I change these movements? For example, add move left, move right.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219947/turtlebot_teleop:-control-moving-around-keys/) by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2015-10-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can see the bindings and change them as you wish in `turtlebot_teleop/scripts/turtlebot_teleop_key` (see https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/indigo/turtlebot_teleop/scripts/turtlebot_teleop_key#L53)

For example, in binding `'m':(-1,-1)`, first element is x velocity, second one is angular velocity.

For your question,

```
'o':(1,-1),
'u':(1,1),
```

**u** makes TurleBot move forward and rotate counter clockwise, while **o** makes it forward and clockwise. Same thing applies for **m** and **.** and others.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-10-27**:
Note that although you can update the directions commanded to include moving sideways. The wheels are rigidly mounted on the bottom of the vehicle in what's called a [differential drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_wheeled_robot) which means it cannot move sideways.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-10-27**:
Yes, Tully is right for sure. @nampi, you need to change URDF and/or drive plugin to make it a holonomic base.